# Dynamic facebook meta tags for fancybox in wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, addthis

I have a site developed in wordpress. There is a product category and there are posts assigned to it, now when a product is clicked, a fancybox opens up. I am trying to have facebook like for the products inside the fancybox using addthis. Now the problem is, when a product is liked a random image is shown instead of the product image. After much research found that I need to set up the facebook meta on the fly, but I am unable to figure out a way to achieve this task. As the page is not reloaded how can I set up the meta tags having the respective images for the products?

The site url is http://havmor.com/products/

Regards,
Joel James

Comment: If you're doing this with any kind of popup box, you need to have a url that the Facebook crawler can access to get the metadata for the fancybox content. That is the url Facebook will show, so you want some kind of client-side script on the page to direct a browser visitor back to the original page with the fancybox shown.

Comment: @cpilko 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product_mid_container_ul > li > a').click(function(){
        var current_image = $(this).children().attr('src');
        $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content", current_image);
        var meta = $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content");
    });
});
I am trying to use this code to change the content value of meta tag, but to no avail, I think each time the page needs to reload with the new meta value which in my case would not be appropriate for a fancybox content

Is there any way by which things could be sorted?

Comment: The Facebook parser doesn't execute javascript. You need server-side or static code to make this work.